# Jquery cycle plugin - multiple divs with multiple after alt

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I would like to make this as easy as it can be, I have tried the approach that you can find under this code, however, I couldn't combine it with multiple afters. I also had a problem with bending the code, for some reason, it works just embed in html but not like embed script. Since I'm using a slider like 15x I really can not leave it like this. Thank you!!

```
$('#down-1').cycle({
      fx: 'scrollDown',
      next: '#down-1',
      timeout: 0,
      speed: 2000,
      fxFn: null,
      preventClicks: false,
      after: function() {
        $('#caption-1').html(this.alt);
      }
    });
    $('#down-2').cycle({
      fx: 'scrollDown',
      next: '#down-2',
      timeout: 0,
      speed: 2000,
      preventClicks: false,
      after: function() {
        $('#caption-2').html(this.alt);
      }
    });
```

example of html

```
 <p1 id="caption-1"></p1>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div id="down-1">
              <img class="lazy" src="img/a.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="I/II"/>
              <img class="lazy" src="img/b.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="II/II"/>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

UPDATE:
Now I have this version but can not make captions work properly, the first alt is always random, the following ones (after sliding) seem right, when I use the same var i the captions do not load at all.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++) {

$('#down-'+ i).cycle({
    fx: 'scrollDown',
    next: '#down-'+ i,
    timeout: 0,
    speed: 2000,
    preventClicks: false,
    // before: null,
    after: function(curr,next,opts) {
      for (var j = 1; j < 12; j++) {
      $("#caption-"+ j).html(this.alt).parent();
    }
    }
  });
}
```

Maybe would help to call this alt from the first one to the following one, maybe the closest alt?

Possible direction? `$(this.alt).children('img:nth(n)')`
should make it work in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

var i;

for (i = 1; i < 12; i++) {

$('#down-'+ i).cycle({

```
fx: 'scrollDown',

next: '#down-'+ i,

timeout: 0,

speed: 2000,

preventClicks: false,

before: function() {

  $('#caption-'+ i).html(this.alt).parent();

},

after: function() {

  $('#caption-'+ i).html(this.alt).parent();

}
```

});

}

You can use variable i for both then it will work please try this

Comment: yes, this does not work at all, if I use var j while scrolling it changes all the captions on page

Answer (score -1):

```
  var i;

  for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

  $('#down-'+ i).cycle({

      fx: 'scrollDown',

      next: '#down-2',

      timeout: 0,

      speed: 2000,

      preventClicks: false,

      after: function() {

        $('#caption-2').html(this.alt);

      }

    });

}
```

Comment: Please consider explaining your code for the benefit of OP and future readers

Comment: I appreciate your answer, thanks, var works for scroll, however, it doesn't work for after - that's not showing at all. Even tho I change the code to 
after: function () {
     $('#caption-' + i).html(this.alt);

would you know how to fix this as well? thanks